# Question mark appears before text instead of after text in using Text widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, text, widget

I am new to Flutter. I wanted to display a simple text in a Flutter app using the Text widget and to my surprise, the question mark appeared before the question instead of after. What could cause that? Here is the snippet:

```
  class _ScreenTwoState extends State<ScreenTwo> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Screen Two"),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    ),
   body: Container(
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          title: Text( _post != null ? "${_post.title}" : "Ooops.... error!!!",
              //this is where the issue is
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,//
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28.9,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                  //height: 50.0
                  ),
              ),
          ),


        ListTile(
            title: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Send back to prev. screen"),
              color: Colors.green,
              highlightColor: Colors.redAccent,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.pop(context, {
                  'info': _backTextFieldController.text
                });
              },
            )
        ),
      ],
    )
  ),
);
```

}
}

To make this clearer, this is what I am expecting

```
 HOW TO FIND A BUS?
```

but this is what I am seeing

```
 ?HOW TO FIND A BUS
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I later found the solution, the problem is with the `textDirection: TextDirection.rtl`. 
Since I am displaying text in ***English not Arabic***, it should be `textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,`